# Google Pub/Sub Topic Creation

Tags: java, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to use the google pub sub emulator on my machine to create a topic.

But when I try to execute the code that creates the topic I get a `TestTimedOutException`.
I am trying to execute the steps/code provide by google on its [documentation page](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/blob/master/pubsub/cloud-client/src/main/java/com/example/pubsub/CreateTopicExample.java).

Here's my code:

```java
public static void main(String args[] ){
   //project id
   String projectId = ServiceOptions.getDefaultProjectId();
   //topic id
   String topicId = args[0];

    // Create a new topic
    ProjectTopicName topic = ProjectTopicName.of(projectId, topicId);
    try (TopicAdminClient topicAdminClient = TopicAdminClient.create()) {
          System.out.println("Topics");
          topicAdminClient.createTopic(topic);
          System.out.printf("Topic %s:%s created.\n", topic.getProject(),                           
                                topic.getTopic());
    } catch(ApiException e) {
       System.out.println(e.getStatusCode().getCode());
       System.out.println(e.isRetryable());
    }
}
```

Error on running example:

```
[INFO] Running com.example.pubsub.QuickStartIT
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 301.26 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.example.pubsub.QuickStartIT
[ERROR] testQuickstart(com.example.pubsub.QuickStartIT)  Time elapsed: 301.153 s  <<< ERROR!
org.junit.runners.model.TestTimedOutException: test timed out after 300 seconds  
        at com.example.pubsub.QuickStartIT.deleteTestSubscription(QuickStartIT.java:144)  
        at com.example.pubsub.QuickStartIT.setUp(QuickStartIT.java:80)
```

Answer (score 0):

The example you are referring to, it is configured to run on the Google Cloud directly. In order to make the example work on your local Pub/Sub emulator, you have to specify in your code that it should be connecting to your emulator host.

The hostport should be added to your code:

```
String hostport = System.getenv("PUBSUB_EMULATOR_HOST");
ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forTarget(hostport).usePlaintext().build();
try {
  TransportChannelProvider channelProvider =
      FixedTransportChannelProvider.create(GrpcTransportChannel.create(channel));
  CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = NoCredentialsProvider.create();

  // Set the channel and credentials provider when creating a `TopicAdminClient`.
  // Similarly for SubscriptionAdminClient
  TopicAdminClient topicClient =
      TopicAdminClient.create(
          TopicAdminSettings.newBuilder()
              .setTransportChannelProvider(channelProvider)
              .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
              .build());

  ProjectTopicName topicName = ProjectTopicName.of("my-project-id", "my-topic-id");
  // Set the channel and credentials provider when creating a `Publisher`.
  // Similarly for Subscriber
  Publisher publisher =
      Publisher.newBuilder(topicName)
          .setChannelProvider(channelProvider)
          .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
          .build();
} finally {
  channel.shutdown();
}
```

You can find more information on how to correctly set up your environment to work with the local Pub/Sub emulator in the [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator#pubsub-emulator-code-sample).